# how to call function in another html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, quick question - I check to see if a checkbox is clicked on an html doc and then when the user clicks on a continue button, it takes them to the next page, which will do stuff based on whether or not that checkbox was checked. What's the easiest way of doing this?

In the index.html file (homepage) I have

```
 if ($("#checkArray").is(":checked")) {
        console.log("permission granted");
      } else {
        console.log("No permissions granted");
     }
window.location='/auth/facebook';
```

which checks to see if the check box is marked. it then goes to the next html document (confirmation.html) for authorization of facebook
here, I want to call a function if the checkbox was checked (true).

Please help! Thanks!!

Comment: You can add a query parameter to the URL if the checkbox was checked, and test for its existence on the other page.

Comment: That would be pretty easy to just mess with I'd think Felix

Comment: Do you think its wise to seperate this checkbox stuff in another page thats used for authentication?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cookies` or `sessionStorage`.

Example with SessionStorage:

```
if ($("#checkArray").is(":checked")) {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('checked', true);
} else {
    window.sessionStorage.setItem('checked', false);
}

window.location='/auth/facebook';
```

And on other page:

```
var checked = window.sessionStorage.getItem('checked');
```

SessionStorage works with modern browsers so if you need to support old browsers like IE8, you should use cookies. You can read more about cookies here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp.

Answer (score 0):

Following Felix Kling

Try

at `index.html`

```
$("input[type='button']").on("click", function(e) {
  var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked");
    if (checked) {
       // do stuff
       // if `_checked` === true
       console.log(checked);        
    } 
    else {
       // do stuff
       // if `_checked` === false
       console.log(checked)
    };
    var conf = window.location.href;
    window.location.href = conf + "?checked=" + checked;
});
```

at `confirmation.html`

```
$(window).on("load", function(e) {
    var _checked = (e.target.location.href
                     .split("?").slice(1,2)[0].split("=")[1] === "true" 
                   ? true 
                   : false
                   );
        if(_checked) {
            // do stuff
            // if `_checked` === true
            console.log(_checked);
        } else {
            // do stuff
            // if `_checked` === false
        };
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/j9t598ab/